# sql query to count tagged posts

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of `newsPosts` where i have a column `tags` in that table.
tags column contains `comma(,)` seperated tags like this.

```
tag1,tag2,tag3
```

in another table  i have list of all tags under tag column
like this :

**tag**

```
tag1
tag2
tag3
tag4
.
.
.
.
```

I want to find number of posts from news post table which are tagged with say tag2.

how can i do this ?  i am using `mysql 5.0`

**EDIT ::**

what i want to do is :::  find tags which are used highest number of times to tag a newsPost.

like this :

```
    tag1 x 100 times
    tag2 x 1000times
                 .
                 .
    tagN x 500 times
```

tag2 should come on the top of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work for all tags from `tags table`:

```
SELECT tag, (SELECT COUNT(1) 
             FROM tag_newPosts t2
             WHERE t2.tag LIKE CONCAT('%',t1.tag,'%')) AS tag_count
FROM tags t1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just say

```
SELECT * FROM newsPosts WHERE tags LIKE '%tag2%'
```

### [Demo at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e68d0/1)

Comment: i don't have tag name (tag2) to insert in this query.. i think i have to join tables ??

Comment: @JAVAGeek . . . then you should ask another question.  This question has already been answered.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM newPosts WHERE tags LIKE "%tag2%";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query with regular expressions:

```
select *
from newsPosts
where tags regexp '(^|,)tag2(,|$)'
```

This expression prevents tags contained inside other tags from making it into the query results. For example, it would select items with `tag2`, but not with `mytag22`.